# abstract class constructor inheritence with inner classes objects

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

Let s say I got an abstract class A. There I got some inner classes like here:

```
public abstract class A
{
        public InnerOne x;
        public InnerTwo y;
        public A(){
           this.x = new InnerOne();
           this.y = new InnerTwo();
        }
        public class InnerOne
        {
            public virtual double value(){
                return 0;
            }
        }
        public class InnerTwo
        {
            public virtual double value(){
                return 0;
            }
        }
}
```

Then I got it's childrens like this one:

```
 public class B: A
    {
            public B():base(){

            }
            public class InnerOne: A.InnerOne
            {
                 public override virtual double value(){
                    return 100;
                }
            }
            public class InnerTwo: A.InnerTwo
            {
                 public override virtual double value(){
                    return 100;
                }
            }
    }
```

So I was think that when I call `B` constructor like that I will initialize `x` and `y` by creating it's inner classes instances. But actually it not works like that. When I call `vaule` functions like here it returns zeros.

```
A newobject = new B();
var bv1 = B.x.value();
var bv2 = B.y.value();
```

Is there way to force `B` class to initialize it's `x` and `y` fields by it's inner class objects (not with objects from parent abstract class) without re-writing it's constructor?

Comment: Why don't you want to modify B constructor?

Comment: Is there a reason you can not or do not want to simple assign them in the constructor for `B`?

Comment: @MichałKomorowski and juharr what if there are too many classes inside?

Comment: Is this a learning exercise? Because if you're trying to solve a real problem, back up a few steps and ask about that problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman nope, I just refactor some stuff on job and just wondered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you have defined the classes inside A or B, they are still public and they are accessible outside A or B. Its no different from a class definied outside A or B.

Imagine the same code with the `InnerOne` and `InnerTwo` defined outside the class A and B. It will have the same above behavior. Your root of confusion is misunderstanding inner class usage.

Inorder to get 100, inside B you need to explicitly replace the instance of X and Y variables with an instance that overrides those values. Unless you do them you will not get 100.

```
 public class B: A
    {
            public B():base(){
            X = new OverridenInnerOne();
            Y = new OverridenInnerTwo();
            }
            public class OverridenInnerOne: A.InnerOne
            {
                 public override virtual double value(){
                    return 100;
                }
            }
            public class OverridenInnerTwo: A.InnerTwo
            {
                 public override virtual double value(){
                    return 100;
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'inner class' aspect (embedded class definition) only distracts here, it plays no role.

And to answer the question: No, you cannot have 'virtual constructors' that work this way.

There are of course plenty of ways to get `100` instead of `0` as returnvalue but the question is too artificial to suggest one.

Comment: there are too many inner classes in abstract class and in each there are `value` function.
I create inner classes instances just to get value functions from inner classes, that why I want to wirte less in constructor :c

Comment: Again: back up and ask about the actual problem. Maybe someone can help, but not this way.

Answer (score 1):

`B.x` and `B.y` are instances of `A.InnerOne` and `A.InnerTwo`, so you're seeing the value returned as 0 as these have nothing to do with `B.InnerOne` or `B.InnerTwo`.

The following `B` constructor would assign `x` and `y` to instances of `B.InnerOne` and `B.InnerTwo` which would return 100.

```
public B(){
    this.x = new InnerOne();
    this.y = new InnerTwo();
}
```

If you wanted `A` to work in the way you expect, you'd need to pass the inner types you wanted through from the `B` constructor and create instances of them in the `A` constructor, something like:

```
   public B():base(typeof(InnerOne),typeof(InnerTwo)) { ... }
```

Using `Activator.CreateInstance` will let you create these types within `A`'s constructor.

Enigmativity's generic solution is better if you always want `A` used this way, alternatively this way allows you to have multiple constructors for `A` so you could optionally pass in different types.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but you must change the definition for class `A` - and it gets super hairy.

Here's `A`:

```
public abstract class A<I1, I2>
    where I1 : A<I1, I2>.InnerOne, new()
    where I2 : A<I1, I2>.InnerTwo, new()
{
    public InnerOne x;
    public InnerTwo y;
    public A()
    {
        this.x = new I1();
        this.y = new I2();
    }
    public class InnerOne
    {
        public virtual double value()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public class InnerTwo
    {
        public virtual double value()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's `B`:

```
public class B: A<B.InnerOne, B.InnerTwo>
{
    public B():base(){ }
    public class InnerOne: A<InnerOne, InnerTwo>.InnerOne
    {
        public override double value()
        {
            return 100;
        }
    }
    public class InnerTwo: A<InnerOne, InnerTwo>.InnerTwo
    {
        public override double value()
        {
            return 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an OOP form of the "Bridge-pattern".